# numba jit: 'DataFlowAnalysis' object has no attribute 'op_STORE_DEREF'

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm trying to run the following code with numba but get an error:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def create_card_deck():
    values = "23456789TJQKA"
    suites = "CDHS"
    Deck = []
    [Deck.append(x + y) for x in values for y in suites]
    return Deck

create_card_deck()
```

Any suggestions what is causing this error are appreciated:

```
'DataFlowAnalysis' object has no attribute 'op_STORE_DEREF'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here - the more fundamental one is that `numba` doesn't support strings in `nopython` mode

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def create_card_deck():
    values = "23456789TJQKA"
    suites = "CDHS"
    return values

In [4]: create_card_deck()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError : Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
cannot convert native str to Python object
```

That specific error is because list comprehensions are also not currently supported in nopython mode.

https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/504

Comment: Looks like lists are not really supported either: `Deck = []` causes `cannot compute fingerprint of empty list`

Comment: Many list operations are actually supported, but subject to the condition that all values have the same type.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to allow lists to be initialised